# What should I tell Siri to set up a reminder on Wednesday at 3pm with text "Team meeting is tomorrow at 4pm"

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, reminders

These phrases and variations don't work:

- Hey Siri, remind me on Wednesday at 3 pm about a meeting tomorrow at 4pm
- Hey Siri, remind me about tomorrow's 4pm Team meeting on Wednesday at 3pm.
- ...

What would be the optimal phrase for Siri to set up the appropriate reminder?

Comment: Create an event, not a reminder. Events show up in calendar and have much better notification tweaks.

Comment: Too complicated. Way more finger movements with compare to talking to Siri.

Comment: Events can be set up with siri too.

Comment: I see this is an old post, but I handle things like this by literally saying "quote" and "end quote", like "Hey Siri, remind me on Wednesday at 3pm that quote team meeting is tomorrow at 4pm end quote". Give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

“Remind me at 3pm today that I have a meeting at 4pm tomorrow”

However, it seems to be inconsistent. Sometimes it set the reminder, and sometimes it asked me what I wanted to be reminded about.

*(Also, I am on the iOS 15 beta, which may or may not matter. I’m not sure.)*